# Уменьшение меню при прокручивании колесом мыши

Tags: javascript

Пример кода здесь:

```
`https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/LjPVym`
```

Проблема в том, что если курсор находится на области меню, то изменения не происходят. Если же курсор поставить на белый фон содержания, то меню плавно уменьшается, как и указано в js-коде.

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса, вместо ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте событие onscroll объекта window

```
window.onscroll = function(event){

    var y = window.pageYOffset;
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    if(y >= 250) {
        menu.style.height = '75px';
        menu.style.transition = '1s';
    }
}
```